# PowerBI: How to use TupleFilter with powerbi-client?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to use [TupleFilter](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/classes/_node_modules_powerbi_models_dist_models_d_.tuplefilter.html) in [powerbi-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client), since I need to filter data based on two different columns with OR statement between them (2 different columns in the same table or may be in 2 different ones), check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078666/power-bi-how-to-use-or-between-2-different-filters) out.

As I read [in this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/filter-api#the-tuple-filter-api-multi-column-filter), tuple filter can do this.

However, when I tried to use it with `report.setFilters(filters)` function, I got this error from setFilters function: "undefined property is invalid".

Moreover, I didn't find the function used in the above docs in powerbi-client:

```
visualHost.applyJsonFilter(filter, "general", "filter", FilterAction.merge)
```

So, I just tried setFilters(filters).

Getting deeper in the [filters docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters), I found this:

> Report level filter supports the following types: IBasicFilter |
>   IAdvancedFilter | IRelativeDateFilter.
>
> Page level filter supports the following types: IBasicFilter | IAdvancedFilter | IRelativeDateFilter.
>
> Visual level filter supports the following types: IBasicFilter | IAdvancedFilter | IRelativeDateFilter | ITopNFilter | IIncludeExcludeFilter.

So, what I couldn't understand, how to use Tuple Filters if none of the above filter levels support it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tuple filter is not supported for embedding

You read correctly, [TupleFilter](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/classes/_node_modules_powerbi_models_dist_models_d_.tuplefilter.html) is not supported in any filter level. It's an API used by [Power BI visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/power-bi-custom-visuals) - so it can be used to create custom slicers (such as [HierarchySlicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820?tab=Overview) - it may solve your issue btw).
Currently however, tuple filters aren't supported for Power BI filters at all, so can't be used with [powerbi-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client) - which deals with embedding a Power BI "element" (report, dashboard, visual etc.) inside a web page or application.

Note that tuple filter support for powerbi-client may be added in the future.

---

Full disclosure: I'm a Microsoft employee, working in one of Power BI's development teams. No affiliation with HierarchySlicer visual.